# Classes gets initialized every time on navigation back and forward swiftUI

Tags: swift, class, swiftui, initialization

I have this navigationStack which has a number of NavigationLinks to game menu's where the user can pick the game to play. This menu consist of navigation links as well which lead to a certain type of the game. The game menu looks like this:

```
struct GameMenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ButtonGame(game_name: "Title", view: AnyView(GameScreen(game: NewGame(count: 4, category: "All"))))
            ButtonGame(game_name: "Title", view: AnyView(GameScreen(game: NewGame(count: 6, category: "2"))))
            ButtonGame(game_name: "Title", view: AnyView(GameScreen(game: NewGame(count: 4, category: "None"))))
            ButtonGame(game_name: "Title", view: AnyView(GameScreen(game: NewGame(count: 4, category: "Basic"))))
        }
    }
}
```

ButtonGame is just a struct which takes a view the NavigationLink should lead to. The view of the game screen takes the NewGame class which handles all the game logic and statistics. This all works fine, but I found that every time I navigate from the main menu to the game menu all these 4 NewGame classes get initialized and also when navigating from the GameMenu to the actual GameView all the NewGame classes get initialized again. Same thing happens when I navigate back from the game view to the game menu view.

This causes unnecessary loading of data and also causes the game to lose its state every time you leave the gameview. How can this be best handled? So that the specific game only gets initialized when the button for that game gets pressed, and that when navigating back to the game menu does not cause everything tot reload again?

Comment: Consider using a StateObject that manages NewGame objects or directly use NewGame as a StateObject so that the state of a game is persisted when going between views.

Comment: `AnyView` is highly discouraged with SwiftUI, you ca watch Demystify SwiftUI for more

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, can you please create a [mcve].

Comment: You're missing some of the SwiftUI fundamentals, namely, that Views aren't like `NSViews` themselves. They're ephemeral descriptions of your view hierarchy. Anytime SwiftUI needs to render a view hierarchy, it'll construct instances of your view structs to ask you "what do you want"? The resulting `View` that's build describes what you want to the SwiftUI rendering system, which it then figures out how to present. You should watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Answer (score 0):

In Swift (and SwiftUI) we use structs instead of classes for model data. The data is always prepared before hand, stored in `@State` and then `body` uses the data to create Views. So just change `Game` to be a struct like this:

```
struct Game: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let count: Int
    let category: String

}

struct GameMenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @State var games = [Game(count: 4, category: "All"), Game(count: 6, category: "2"), Game(count: 4, category: "None"), Game(count: 4, category: "Basic")]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($games) { $game in
                ButtonGame(gameName: "Title", game: $game)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonGame: View {

    @Binding var game: Game
```